# A large amount of points to create separate polygons (ArcGIS/QGIS)

Tags: polygon, arcgis, qgis, points

[Visual example of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYU6w.png)

I used a drone to create a DOF of a small area. During the flight, it takes a photo every 20sh seconds (40sh meters of a flight). I have created a CSV file, which I transferred to a point shapefile. In total, I made with drone 10 so-called "missions", each with 100-200 points which are "shaped" as squares on the map. What I want now is to create a polygon shapefile from the point shapefile.

Because those points sometimes overlap, I cannot use the "Aggregate Points" task, as it's only distance-based. I want to make polygons automatically, using some kind of script. What could help is the fact that a maximum time between two points (AKA photos taken) is 10-20 seconds, so if the time distance is over 3 minutes, it's another "mission". Can you help with such a script, that would quickly and automatically create as many polygons as there are missions?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I understand what you are trying to accomplish. Since no one replied I am going to give it a quick shot, so you have something to try.

I think the best strategy would be to:

1. ***Clustering algorithm*:** Try running a Clustering algorithm such as `DBSCAN` around the timestamp dimension to classify them based on time groups, instead of the distance (since, as you said, distance based separation is not enough to properly identify and separate the points). After which, you should have all the points classified between different groups with a column group id. Maximum distance parameter in the algorithm should be around 20 seconds steps, or even a minute (since you said each mission was separated at least about 3 minutes apart).
2. ***Feature based Polygon to point*:** At that point, then you run your generic `Polygon_from_points(...)` function that transforms these clustered points to polygons shapes *based on a specific discriminant feature* (which in your case is going to be each group id).

*How does this work?*: This would properly separate the groups first (time-based) and then you should be able to find a generic point to polygon based on a feature (Arcgis should have some).

I dont have an example dataset, nor any code written, but based on what you described I think it would work, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It actually helps, as I did use DBSCAN before. I would transfer the information of date/time to seconds and basically check for jumps of, say, 100 seconds (I could easily use 3 minutes but it's unnecessary). I think I might use R for this. Thanks again.

Comment: Let me know if this could be marked as the accepted answer